# TextInput momentarily displays value before onChange gets fired

Tags: react-native

I have a simple text input field that accepts only numbers as the input. The `onChange` handler checks to see that the provided value is valid and then sets the state. If, however, validation fails, then it does nothing.

Everything works as expected, however the behavior seems strange to me. If validation fails, I still see the incorrectly provided value for a moment. It then goes away, but I feel like there's something wrong here.

What I would like to do is replicate the behavior that the `maxLength` prop provides. When set to an integer, it does absolutely nothing (as is expected and as it should) if the provided value's length is larger than the max length. However, in my current case, I'd like to validate the input first and make sure that the value is all numbers.

Perhaps there are some native modules that I can make changes to? How can I get this to work?

Here's how it looks at the moment:

[image: img1]

Here's the code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const MAX_LENGTH = 6;
const MyComponent = React.memo(() => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
        const isValidInput = (!e.trim() || !!parseInt(e)) && !/[a-z]/gi.test(e);

        if (isValidInput && e.length <= MAX_LENGTH) {
            setValue(e);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <TextInput
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder='Type only numbers...'
        />
    );
});
```

From the React-Native docs regarding [`maxLength`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#maxlength):

> Limits the maximum number of characters that can be entered. Use this instead of implementing the logic in JS to avoid **flicker**

And so this leaves me questioning if what I'd like to do is possible.

There's also [this recent comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23578#issuecomment-1895073796) on GitHub by the maintainer of the `TextInput` component. It seems as though this issue hasn't been fixed thus far.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an unresolved issue in react-native, but there is hope! It sounds like there may be an effort to fix this:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23578

Comment: I already linked that GitHub thread in the OP :) I guess we wait for the fix, if it ever comes

Comment: Whoops... I should have refreshed the page before commenting LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use onKeyPress and setNativeProps to reset the Input back to value quicker. onKeyPress fires before onChange but only delivers one char.

Users won't see any flicker except for lowEnd devices or first char.

```
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  const handleChange = (text) => {
    //... change value if should
  };

  const onKeyPress = () => {
    inputRef.current.setNativeProps({ text: value });
  };

  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={inputRef}
      value={value}
      onChangeText={handleChange}
      placeholder="Type only numbers..."      
      onKeyPress={onKeyPress}      
    />
  );
```

For absolute zero flicker, you could

- add a Text after InputText and wrap both inside a View.
- Pass the same value props to both.
- The Text would be below TextInput with absolute position and same fontSize.
- Set TextInput color to 'transparent' and set caretHidden to true.

Still, If you need to show a caret you can show a custom one next to Text.

Answer (score 0):

To minimise flickering and only accept a certain number of numeric characters, something like this would work:

```js
<TextInput
  maxLength={MAX_LENGTH}
  keyboardType="numeric"
  value={value}
  onChangeText={(e) => {
    if (/^\d+$/.test(e)) setValue(e);
  }}
  placeholder="Type only numbers..."
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've actually already tried this, but unfortunately, I need to format the input as well. For instance, I have a phone input field. As the user types, the number gets formatted as `(111) 111-11-11`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point validating the input type of your TextInput. Just set inputMode to numeric. This input field will not react to anything but numbers. See https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#inputmode

```js
     import * as React from 'react';
     import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

      const MAX_LENGTH = 6;
      const MyComponent = React.memo(() => {
      const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

       const handleChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
        if ( e.length <= MAX_LENGTH) {
            setValue(e);
        }
      }, []);

      return (
        <TextInput
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            inputMode="numeric"
            placeholder='Type only numbers...'
        />
      );
    });
```

Comment: There is a point, because I need to format the input before setting it (for instance, as a phone number: `(111) 111-11-11`